# A princely romance

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, story

> The prince was nervous as he chariot approached the woman's house. He knew he was being direct showing up at her door unannounced like this, but he knew the feelings he had for her were not imaginary. He was going to finally be a man, knock on her door and personally invite her to an afternoon meal.
>
> The prince stepped out of the chariot and awkwardly straightened his royal headgear. His entire 250-lbs body was trembling of excitement. He was one of the most powerful people on the continent, yet a simple "no" from her would reduce him into a pile of small stones.
>
> He knocked. A simple smile and a positive answer from her, and he would know that he had triumphed. That he had been right to show up like this. He was putting it all on the line. Everyone who's anyone in court would know that he did this, and they would hear of her answer as well.
>
> As she opened the door, the pleasant smell of her hair was intoxicating. He got himself together  and politely extended his invitation. A lovely smile on her face, she said

...

> yes.
>
>  (Not part of the puzzle. Just didn't want to leave you hanging.)

Can you guess the woman's name?

Comment: Is this trivia like, as in we need to find someone in the oldern days (maybe rome) that proposed to a women or something?

Comment: No history knowledge needed @PotatoLatte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pehaps the woman's name is:

> **Lira**?

Here's the same story again, but slightly reworded:

> The prince was nervous as he chariot approached the woman's house. He knew he was being direct showing up at her door unannounced like this, but he knew the feelings he had for her were **real**. He was going to finally be a man, knock on her door and personally invite her to **dinner**/**dinar**.
>
>  The prince stepped out of the chariot and awkwardly straightened his **crown**. His entire 250-**pounds** body was trembling of excitement. He was one of the most powerful people on the continent, yet a simple "no" from her would reduce him into a pile of **rubble**/**rubles**.
>
>  Ding **dong**! A simple smile and a positive answer from her, and he would know that he had **won**. That he had been right to show up like this. He was **frank**. **Some**/**som** in court would know that he did this, and they would hear of her answer as well.
>
>  As she opened the door, the **tang**/**tenge** of her hair was intoxicating. He got himself together  and politely extended his invitation. A lovely smile on her face, she said "yes"!

Every sentence ...

> ... has the name of a national currency (or a slight variation thereof). I'm sure I've missed some, especially in the first sentence. I have not  considered digital or obsolete currencies.
>
>  I've just picked a valid currency that sounds like a woman's name. (The Turkish Lira, but the Nigerian Naira is also a possibility.) Maybe there's more to it and we have to look at either the issuing country or the the three-letter code or the name of the smaller unit, the "pennies" of these currencies, but given that there are so many countries whose currency are pounds, dinars or crowns, that doesn't look likely to me.

Comment: I had rot13[fprag] for the pleasant smell and rot13[Craal] for the woman's name, but your reasoning works just as well :) Nice work!